# NodeJS measure an execution time that takes at least 10 microseconds

Tags: node.js, process, raspberry-pi, interrupt, timing

In my computer the below code takes `60-70 microseconds`

```
var start = process.hrtime()[1];

// calling this method again takes 60 microseconds!  
var end   = process.hrtime()[1];
console.log(((end-start) / 1000) + " microsconds"); // ~60 microseconds
```

Now I need to trigger an [ultrasonic sensor](https://www.google.com/search?q=ultrasonic%20sr05) by setting its `trigger` pin to `HIGH` for **10 microseconds**. then switch it off.

[image: how ultrasonic sensor works]

Then read the `echo` pin from where it's `0(LOW)` until it changes to `HIGH` and measure that time which is a number in microseconds between `100-25000 microseconds`.

The problem is when `process.hrtime()` itself takes 60 microseconds, I can not measure time difference with 10 microseconds accuracy. Obviously there are other codes may affect the performance that affects the output.

Comment: This probably isn't a solution to your issue by itself, but you're measuring the time diff wrong.  If the nanoseconds value rolls over to increase the seconds value, then you will get a wrong measurement.  There's an example of calculating diff properly [in the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time).

Comment: FYI, when I code this to correctly measure the time diff, I get 16 to 18 microseconds on my computer.

Comment: @jfriend00, I know about more than 1 second issue and it doesn't matter right now! At this time I'm looking for a solution of high speed execution.

Comment: It doesn't appear you can control things at a 10 microsecond resolution with node.js using this mechanism on a raspberry pi.  Not sure if there's some other way.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, also python sample code didn't work well and it is not even close to be accurate.(goo.gl/W8dGST)